# Excel VBA Open a workbook from dropbox then Save/Close Current Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, path, dropbox

Ok here is the code I have tried so far:

```
Dim myFileName As String, DTAddress As String, ans As String, DBPathEstim As String
     Dim sPath As String, stPath As String, WB1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook, OriginFile As String
        ' Send the workbook to clients
        myFileName = Worksheets("EstimatingSheet").Range("U11").Value & ".xls"
        sPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

        stPathClients = Left(sPath, InStrRev(sPath, "\") - 1) & "\Clients\" & myFileName
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs stPathClients

        ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Ok I would like to open a workbook.  The work book path may be different for different users because we use dropbox.  So it will always be .....\Dropbox\SSFiles\Estimating 2016.xls

Comment: Two choices: 1) Use [GetOpenFilename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195744(v=office.11).aspx) which allows user to pick the file to open. 2) Do a test for the operating system and then build the string where a DropBox folder would typically be installed. (this is obviously not foolproof since a user could put it anywhere.

Comment: This may help http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/05/05/find-your-dropbox-folder-in-vba/

Comment: This help article has information about an official method for finding the local Dropbox folder path(s): https://www.dropbox.com/help/4584

Answer (score 1):

In my case the "info.json" file shows the path as:

```
"C:\\Users\\[USER]\\Dropbox"
```

It uses double "\" characters. The [article](https://www.dropbox.com/help/4584) provided says it should appear like this:

```
"C:\Users\[USER]\Dropbox"
```

Whatever your case is, this code works to get the Dropbox path wherever is located:

```
Function GetDropboxPath() As String
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    '* Locates the Dropbox user path by usign the local "info.json" file. ************'
    '* Wrote by cesarmades ***********************************************************'
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

    ' Loads the local info.json file
    Dim intFile As Integer: intFile = FreeFile
    Open VBA.Interaction.Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\AppData\Local\Dropbox\info.json" For Input As #intFile

    ' Stores info.json file content in a variable
    Dim strFileContent As String: strFileContent = Input(LOF(intFile), intFile)
    Close #intFile

    ' Trims the string and returns the path
    Dim intIPos As Integer: intIPos = VBA.Strings.InStr(1, strFileContent, """path""", vbTextCompare) + 9
    Dim intFPos As Integer: intFPos = VBA.Strings.InStr(1, strFileContent, """host""", vbTextCompare) - 3

    GetDropboxPath = VBA.Strings.Replace(Mid(strFileContent, intIPos, intFPos - intIPos), "\\", "\")
End Function
```